# WFS GetFeature request via http POST does not work with ArcGIS

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis, geoserver, arcgis-server

The following WFS GetFeature request works with no problem with Geoserver but it fails with ArcGIS.

JavaScript call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://......",
        data: "...",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
        },
        dataType: 'xml',
        error: function (xhr,status,error){
            console.debug(status + " - "+ error);
        },
        success: callBack
    });
```

POST body (data):

```
<GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs  http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<Query typeName="WellHole" srsName="EPSG:3857">
<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
<PropertyIsEqualTo>
<PropertyName>OBJECTID</PropertyName>
<Literal>402</Literal>
</PropertyIsEqualTo>
</Filter>
</Query>
</GetFeature>
```

JavaScript error (client):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://..../MapServer/WFSServer. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400
```

ArcGIS server error (server):

```
Error handling request to service 'Target/OGDR_Fahud.MapServer'. AutomationException: 0x80070057 - Invalid http method. in '"esriGeoDatabaseDistributed.WFSServer"'

com.esri.arcgis.discovery.ejb.ArcGISServiceException: AutomationException: 0x80070057 - Invalid http method. in '"esriGeoDatabaseDistributed.WFSServer"' 
at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.ejb.impl.GenericServerBean.handleRequest(GenericServerBean.java:72) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3891.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:162) at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:144) at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:164) at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:92) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3890.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:162) at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:144) at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:122) at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:221) at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:174) at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:136) at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:238) at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:129) at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:196) at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:149) at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:71) at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.KeepAliveServer$Session.service(KeepAliveServer.java:213) at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.KeepAliveServer.service(KeepAliveServer.java:233) at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:66) at org.apache.openejb.server.ServicePool$2.run(ServicePool.java:91) at org.apache.openejb.server.ServicePool$3.run(ServicePool.java:120) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.esri.arcgis.discovery.servicelib.AGSException: AutomationException: 0x80070057 - Invalid http method. in '"esriGeoDatabaseDistributed.WFSServer"' at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.servicelib.impl.RemoteServiceImpl.handleRequest(RemoteServiceImpl.java:98) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276) at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253) at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162) at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227) at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.handleRequest(Unknown Source) at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.ejb.util.EJBBase.handleRequestBase(EJBBase.java:548) at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.ejb.impl.GenericServerBean.handleRequest(GenericServerBean.java:70) ... 29 more Caused by: java.lang.Exception: AutomationException: 0x80070057 - Invalid http method. in '"esriGeoDatabaseDistributed.WFSServer"' at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.servicelib.impl.ServiceImpl.handleRequest(ServiceImpl.java:244) at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.servicelib.impl.RemoteServiceImpl.handleRequest(RemoteServiceImpl.java:92) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) ... 3 more Caused by: AutomationException: 0x0 - null at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.nativeVtblInvokeNative(Native Method) at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.nativeVtblInvoke(Unknown Source) at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.invoke(Unknown Source) at com.esri.arcgis.interop.Dispatch.vtblInvoke(Unknown Source) at com.esri.arcgis.system.IWebRequestHandlerProxy.handleStringWebRequest(Unknown Source) at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.servicelib.impl.SOThread.a(SOThread.java:1010) at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.servicelib.impl.SOThread.a(SOThread.java:692) at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.servicelib.impl.SOThread.run(SOThread.java:446)
```

And I have also noticed the following:

1) If I use the POST request above (same code) with Geoserver's TestServlet (demo section on the web interface) it works.

2) The following http GET request works with ArcGIS:

```
http://..../MapServer/WFSServer?service=WFS&request=getfeature&version=1.1.1&typename=wellhole&Filter=%3Cogc:Filter%3E%3Cogc:PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3Cogc:PropertyName%3EOBJECTID%3C/ogc:PropertyName%3E%3Cogc:Literal%3E402%3C/ogc:Literal%3E%3C/ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3C/ogc:Filter%3E
```

Please help.

Comment: looks to be a CORS issue (preflight suggests that)

Comment: I think I have checked that. Why would it work from Geoserver's test servlet? It also works from a HttpPost method in java. Not sure what's wrong from JavaScript

Comment: looks like a CORS issue then - of course, I'm assuming (probably wrongly) that there is a browser involved in this question - looking again, it doesn't look like it, so CORS would not be an issue for server side code

Comment: I take that back - jQuery means browser, right - so either the server doesn't understand the request, or it's not configured for CORS at all ... the preflight sends a OPTIONS method request with exactly the same headers/data that you specify in your POST request - the server needs to respond correctly for the preflight to "pass" - the server you are connecting to does not, but a 400 error doesn't really say if the problem is "no CORS for you" or "BAD REQUEST" (which is what a 400 error is)

Comment: I used http://www.test-cors.org/ and it seems to be ok. I wonder if ArcGIS expects a different request format.

Comment: Check what the GeoServer log file says

Comment: How can I configure arcgis server for CORS? Where shall I add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin property/config? I could do it easily in Apache/Geoserver but how can I do it in arcgis server running on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I think this problem could be missing namespace in your POST request body.

Maybe you could try to add namespace in each tag like following example and let us know?

```
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:cgf="http://www.opengis.net/cite/geometry" outputFormat="GML2" version="1.0.0" service="WFS">
<wfs:Query typeName="esri:we">
<ogc:Filter>
<ogc:BBOX>
<ogc:PropertyName>gml:multiPointProperty</ogc:PropertyName>
<gml:Box xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/cite/spatialTestSuite" srsName="EPSG:4326">
<gml:coordinates>-122.087210506228, 37.208402, -121.813389493772, 37.383473</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Box>
</ogc:BBOX>
</ogc:Filter>
</wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

Comment: I tried with the code above and it did not work neither. Any other hint?

Answer (score -1):

I just tried with namespaces but I got the same output.

```
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" 
                       service="WFS" version="1.1.0" 
                       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs 
                       http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<wfs:Query typeName="WellHole" srsName="EPSG:3857" >
<ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
<ogc:PropertyName>OBJECTID</ogc:PropertyName>
<ogc:Literal>402</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
</wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```